# Ionic 2 : Screen Orientation like portrait and landscape in android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

when i rotate the screen in both direction portrait and landscape but android application of ionic 2 is not rotate

config.xml

```
<preference name='orientation' value='portrait'/>
```

app.component.js

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';

initializeApp() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => { 
if (this.platform.isPortrait) { this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE); } else {  this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT); }
    this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    this.initPushNotification();  
}); 
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i want to rotate the application with phone's screen orientation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer of this question, when phone screen orientation change application also rotate with phone orientation.

first, remove orientation preference from confix.xml

then this code write in app.component.js

app.component.js

```
if (this.platform.is('android')) {        
    this.ScreenOrientation.onChange().subscribe(() => {

      if (this.platform.isPortrait) {
        this.ScreenOrientation.unlock()
      }
      else {            
        this.ScreenOrientation.lock(this.ScreenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT_PRIMARY)
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible for a single page ?

Answer (score 2):

First install ..

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

npm install --save @ionic-native/screen-orientation

app.component.ts

```
 import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';

 constructor(private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) { }

 // set to landscape

this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);

// allow user rotate

this.screenOrientation.unlock();





  or 

   constructor(private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) {
    this.screenOrientation.lock('portrait');
   }
```